# Get concat to work with an array-like object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

There are places I change an array to an array like object like so:

```
let arr = ['a','b']
let arrLike = {...arr, length: arr.length}
console.log(arrLike)
> {0: "a", 1: "b", length: 2}
```

It's not perfect, but this allows me to override arrays by using a merge. ie:

```
> let a1 = [1,2,3], b1 = [1,2,3]
> Object.assign(a1, arr)
[ 'a', 'b', 3 ]
> Object.assign(b1, arrLike)
[ 'a', 'b']
```

which is desirable but I would also like concat to work,

```
['z'].concat(arr)
> ["z", "a", "b"] // good
['z'].concat(arrLike)
> ["z", {0: "a", 1: "b" length: 2}] // bad
```

Is there anyway to modify `arrLike` such that concat would work?

Comment: In order to convert an array-like object into a true array use Array's `slice` method in conjunction with Function's `call`: `Array.prototype.slice.call(arrLike)`

Comment: @hindmost: That's not what he wants

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define [`Symbol.isConcatSpreadable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/isConcatSpreadable) to tell `concat()` to treat it as array-like:

```
arrLike[Symbol.isConcatSpreadable] = true;
```

Example:

```js
let arr = ['a','b'];
let arrLike = {
  ...arr, 
  length: arr.length,
  [Symbol.isConcatSpreadable]: true
};

console.log(['z'].concat(arrLike))
```

Comment: Wow. how do you find this?

Comment: @lonewarrior556: By searching the [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) for `concat`.